# SQL update only new or changed records in table

Tags: sql, insert

I am not looking for an answer here rather more of a shove in the right direction.  I have a table on a datawarehouse server containing customer information, and I would like to create a stored procedure/job that updates that table nightly from the live version of the table.  However, there are a lot of records, so I don't want to truncate and re-populate that data each time.  I would like to insert any new records and update only records that have changed... for example a customers email changed.

I am just looking for suggestions on the best way to approach this to minimize overhead on the system.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which database are you using? Which version?

Comment: How many records a day are updated?  How many are brand new?

Answer (score 3):

You don't say which database product you are using.  But some modern flavours of DMBS support the `MERGE` SQL statement.  For instance [Oracle has had it since 9i](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9016.htm), and [SQL Server since 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).  [DB2 version 9 has it](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0010873.htm) (don't know when IBM introduced it).

The MySQL equivalent is [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/05/25/mysql-merge-gone-awry/), which isn't quite as versatile.

If your database doesn't support the syntax you'll need to handcode an UPSERT statement.  This will be of the form

```
begin
    update your_table
          set col1 = 23
          when pk_col = 42;
exception
    when no_data_found then
        insert into your_table (pk_col, col1)
        values (42, 23);
end;
```